# Showing the part of a hidden DIV within a DIV

Tags: css

I'm missing something obvious today, guys - would appreciate some help please.

I've got a horizontal row of DIVs inside another DIV.  I want the third DIV to show as partly hidden by the top DIV.  But it isn't showing at all.

Here's the CSS:

```
.outer {
    background: #800;
    height: 90px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.label {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background: #888;
    width: 75px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="label">1</div>
    <div class="label">2</div>
    <div class="label">3</div>
    <div class="label">4</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm missing something obvious today, guys - would appreciate some help
>   please.

The "obvious" thing you're missing is that the third and fourth inner `div`s are dropping underneath because there is not enough horizontal space. For instance, if I check it using Chrome's Developer Tools:

[image]

The simplest way to fix this is to switch from `float: left` to `display: inline-block`, with `white-space: nowrap` (you already have it!) on the containing element:

http://jsfiddle.net/rGfNY/

Comment: nice idea, defenately less work than mine, but doesn't inline-block give issues (in some IE versions)?

Comment: jsFiddle seems slow, so `display:inline-block; *display:inline; zoom:1` fixes it for older versions of IE.

Answer (score 2):

you need to wrap them in a new div, give the div a width, (bigger than your outer div) it will be cut off by the outer div's overflow hidden.

on thing to note: the width of that inner div is not adjusting with the content, either you specifically set it very high, or you have to calculate it to the content either just put it hardcoded in css, or use javascript.

html:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="label">1</div>
        <div class="label">2</div>
        <div class="label">3</div>
        <div class="label">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.outer {
    background: #800;
    height: 90px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.inner {
    width: 460px;
}
.label {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background: #888;
    width: 75px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/f2wpm/

Comment: Many thanks, Sander, much appreciated.  I've accepted thirtydot's answer because it avoids creating another DIV.

Comment: in my eyes it depends on the amount of times you  have to add the extra div.. if only once i'd choose the div over hacking in css to make it work in IE, but you could of course use conditional styles too if you want it to work in IE